# What is the best way to track Business Development and Donor Intel

Tags: activities, best-practice, multi-record, organization

I work for a nonprofit and we are trying to figure out the best way to document and track business development work such as Intel into potential donors or conversations various execs have had with an individual and keep it in Civi. For instance, if my CEO goes to talk to Mr. Smith and Mr. Smith gives us all kinds of information about Foundation ABC even if they don't work there then what is the best way to keep track of all of that information? Is it through activities and then just adding all mentioned parties as contact with? Or is there an extension or organization method that my CEO could just click on Foundation ABC and find all relevant notes to that FOundation to help make the ask that much better?

We are hoping to use Civi not only for our donor tracking but also business and grant development too and we can't seem to find the best way to organize to make that happen.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Let us know your CMS. Drupal lets you build easy interfaces so you can have a list of all your Orgs and then click through from there to see a summary of just the Activities that are used for your conversations.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of Activities. This enables you to then track converations, and have different Activity Types for different 'types' of leads etc.

Comment: Is there anyway to make an addition to activities to include "Mentions" as well as "with contact" so that way it's clear that they weren't at that meeting but were metioned

Comment: Maybe just make another Activity Type of 'Mentioned by'? I don't really understand your 'user story' well enough though

Comment: Or add a Custom Field of type Contact Reference on the Activity Type

Comment: thanks! this really helps. I'll meet up with my drupal coding expert and see what we can make work.